# Plotly can't display png images in subplots

Tags: python, html, plotly

Is there any way to put png image instead of one of this Scatter graphs?
I could only find how to use the image as logo or background image

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6]),
    row=1, col=1
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[20, 30, 40], y=[50, 60, 70]),
    row=1, col=2
)

fig.update_layout(height=600, width=800, title_text="Side By Side Subplots")
fig.show()
```

I tried to add this lines before `fig.update_layout`

```
from PIL import Image
import plotly.express as px
img = Image.open('plot1.png')
plotly_img = px.imshow(img)
fig.add_trace(go.Image(plotly_img), row=1, col=2)
#fig.add_trace(go.Image(img), row=1, col=2)
```

but it doesn't work

> ValueError: The first argument to the plotly.graph_objs.Image
> constructor must be a dict or
> an instance of :class:`plotly.graph_objs.Image`

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is to use [base64 example](https://linuxhint.com/plotly-graph-objects-image/)

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from skimage importdata
import base64
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

img = data.astronaut()
img_obj = Image.fromarray(img)
prefix = "data:image/png;base64,"
with BytesIO() as stream:
    img_obj.save(stream, format='png')
    b64_str = prefix + base64.b64encode(stream.getvalue()).decode('unicode_escape')
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Image(
    source=b64_str
))
fig.show()
```